# Is my rspec test failing because of mysql timestamp format?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have an rspec test that keeps failing and the only thing I can think of that might be causing the problem is that the format of `created_at` the test is generating is a mysql timestamp, which isn't being translated properly in the application itself. Here is my `reminders_spec.rb` test, where I'm sampling from an array containing variables of `Reminders::LIMBO_EMAIL_INTERVAL_DAYS` (set to 3) to establish the condition that the `created_at` date is one in which an email should be sent:

```
describe '#send_peer_shortage_notifications' do
   subject { described_class.send_peer_shortage_notifications }

        context 'minimum number of peer assessments not in pending/complete and limbo email interval day' do
          limbo_interval_array = Array.new(10) { |i| i*Reminders::LIMBO_EMAIL_INTERVAL_DAYS }

          let!(:evaluation) { create(:evaluation, created_at: (Evaluation::ASSESSMENTS_COMPLETION_WAIT_TIME + limbo_interval_array.sample.days).ago) }
          let!(:assessments) do
            create_list(:assessment,
            Evaluation::MINIMUM_NUM_PEERS,
            evaluation: evaluation,
            state: [:expired, :declined].sample)
          end

          it 'sends limbo email' do
            puts evaluation.created_at
            expect { subject }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
          end
        end
```

The output of `puts evaluation.created_at` is in mysql timestamp format (i.e. `2016-04-01 19:44:43 UTC`), which doesn't respond to formatting like `.to_date` which I think may be causing my tests to fail. Here is the failure message:

```
Failures:

  1) Reminders#send_peer_shortage_notifications minimum number of peer assessments not in pending/complete and limbo email interval day sends limbo email
     Failure/Error: expect { subject }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
       expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/lib/reminders_spec.rb:110:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's the logic in `reminders.rb` where I use `.to_date` and `to_i` in order to figure out `days_in_limbo` and set the conditions for sending the email:

```
def self.send_peer_shortage_notifications
    time = Time.current - Evaluation::ASSESSMENTS_COMPLETION_WAIT_TIME
    range = time..Time.current
    today = Time.current.to_date

    evaluations = Evaluation.arel_table
    assessments = Assessment.arel_table

    left_join = evaluations
                .join(assessments, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
                .on(evaluations[:id].eq(assessments[:evaluation_id]),
                    assessments[:state].in([:pending, :complete]),
                    assessments[:assessor_id].not_in([evaluations[:user_id],
                                                      evaluations[:manager_id]]))
                .join_sources

    relation = Evaluation
               .in_process
               .joins(left_join)
               .where(created_at: range)
               .group(:user_id)
               .having(evaluations[:user_id].count.lt(Evaluation::MINIMUM_NUM_PEERS))

    relation.find_each do |evaluation|
      days_in_limbo = (today - (evaluation.created_at + Evaluation::ASSESSMENTS_COMPLETION_WAIT_TIME).to_date).to_i
      if days_in_limbo > 0 && days_in_limbo % Reminders::LIMBO_EMAIL_INTERVAL_DAYS == 0
        EvaluationMailer.delay.limbo_notification(evaluation)
      end
    end
  end
```

**Note**: I just want to know why this test isn't passing, either due to formatting or otherwise, and if there's a way to convert the format in rspec so it's passing information that can be formatted by Rails. I'm not looking for alternate solutions to the logic such as modifying my cron jobs or using gems like `whenever` or `timecop`, but thanks anyway if that's what you were going to suggest :)

Comment: what is your rspec error?

Comment: sorry...should have included that! `Failures:

  1) Reminders#send_peer_shortage_notifications minimum number of peer assessments not in pending/complete and limbo email interval day sends limbo email
     Failure/Error: expect { subject }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
       expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/lib/reminders_spec.rb:110:in block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'`

Comment: better edit question)

Comment: also, include part of code with your `subject`

Comment: There's a lot going on in your question that isn't really relevant - try and narrow it down. For example it could be that the number of emails doesn't change because your test environment is queueing the emails to be sent by sidekiq/ delayed job, or it could be that the query returns no results or it could be that your condition in the find_each block always returns false. Work out which one of those is happen and then you can dramatically cut down your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @FrederickCheung. It ended up being an issue with the range variable but will keep this in mind for future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all comments/responses. The issue ended up being the `range` variable not including evaluations with the `created_at` dates that I was testing for.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure from the information provided but I don't think the state of your database is changing within the `expect...change` block as you're expecting it to. I also don't think using `subject` is appropriate in this case.

I'm guessing if you replaced `subject` with the content of your `let`s you might get a passing test. You can also try using `let` instead of `let!` since `let!` will run before the examples.